# Can a symmetric bilinear map $V\times V \to W$ increase subspace dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ and $W$ be two finite-dimensional real vector spaces, and let $S$ be a subspace of $V$. By the rank-nullity theorem, if $T$ is a linear map $V \to W$, then $\dim T(S) \leq \dim S$.

Now, let $B$ denote a symmetric bilinear map $V \times V \to W$. I would like to know if a similar statement holds for $B$.

More precisely, consider the subspace defined by the span of the image of $B\lvert_{S\times S}$:
$$
B(S)=\mathrm{span}\,\{B(x,y) \mid x,y \in S \}.
$$
Is it true that $\dim B(S) \leq \dim S$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $V = \mathbb{R}^2_{\textrm{col}}$ and consider the map $B \colon V \times V \rightarrow M_2(\mathbb{R})$ given by $B(x,y) = \frac{1}{2} \left( x \cdot y^T + y \cdot x^T \right)$. Then

$$ B(e_1,e_1) = e_1 \cdot e_1^T = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \\
B(e_1,e_2) = \frac{1}{2} \left( \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\\
B(e_2,e_2) = e_2 \cdot e_2^T = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.   $$

This means that $B(V)$ is the subspace of $2 \times 2$ symmetric matrices which is three dimensional while $V$ has dimension two.

Comment: @MK7: More abstractly, the map $B$ induces a linear map $T_B \colon S^2(V) \rightarrow W$ for which the rank-nullity theorem applies. Given a subspace $U \leq V$, the "image" $B(U)$ is precisely $T_B \left( S^2(U) \right)$ so by rank-nullity we have $\dim B(U) \leq \dim S^2(U)$. Unfortunately, if $\dim U = k$ then $\dim S^2(U) = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ so you only get $\dim B(U) \leq \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ and not $\dim B(U) \leq k$. In my example, $U = V$ and $k = 2$ and you indeed get $\dim B(U) = 3$.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks a lot for the detailed answer!